# Iframe code for adding Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I wish to add the Facebook like button to my Google web site.  I have been told that I need to use the iFrame code for this. I have followed the procedure for generating the code via Facebook and I get the HTLM5 and XFMBL code but not the Iframe code. Instead I get a message

"This plugin does not have an iFrame implementation with the selected options. Please use the JavaScript SDK and the HTML5 or XFBML implementations, or change the value of the send parameter."

Why this is?

Comment: why do you only need iframe plugin 
i asked this because maybe after knowing this i will find any other way of exit

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're seeing that problem because you haven't unticked the «Send Button» checkbox.

From [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> There are two Like button implementations: XFBML and Iframe. The XFBML
>   (also available in HTML5-compliant markup) version is more versatile,
>   but requires use of the JavaScript SDK.

If, for some reason (and I can't see why), you really need the iFrame version, play with the plugin options until you find a combination which works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the option "send button", because it is only available if you do not use the iframe code.